# What are these flower like cells in the photo attached?

Tags: hematology

[image: RBC]

I am a student of BSc. Zoology... I was doing a TC of RBC of my blood when I encountered these strange flower like cells. Are they lysed RBCs ? If so, why are they so geometric in shape ?